# error with NDSolve

Tags: plotting, differential-equations

I'm trying to plot  u as a function of t by NDSolving a set ODE's

The problem is like:

Parameters:

```
time = 100;m = 2;rE = 1000;rE2 = 100;sr = 5;d = 5;a = 0.001;k = 2;Ta = 15000;n = 0.2;\[Tau] = 1/(\[Pi]^2 + k^2);
```

The system of the differential equations:

```
soln = NDSolve[{Derivative[1][u][t] == 
 k^2 \[Tau] Ta v[t] + u[t]/(n - 1) + 
  16/(3 \[Pi]) Ta k^2 \[Tau] v[t] s[t], 
Derivative[1][v][t] == \[Pi] u[t] w[t] + u[t] - v[t]/(n \[Tau]), 
Derivative[1][w][
  t] == -((3 m^2 n rE)/( (2 - 3 n + n^2) \[Pi] rE2)) + \[Pi]/
   2 u[t] v[t] + (4 \[Pi]^2)/n w[t], 
Derivative[1][s][t] == -((4 k n )/(rE2 (1 - n) \[Pi])) f[t] + (
  4 m n rE (m Sqrt[2 - n] + (-2 + n) Tanh[m/Sqrt[2 - n]]))/((2 - 
     n)^(3/2) (-1 + n) rE2 \[Pi]) - \[Pi]^2/n  s[t]  , 
Derivative[1][f][t] == (
  n (4 + a (d (k^2 + \[Pi]^2) + \[Pi]^2 sr)) f[t])/( 
  a (-1 + n) ) +  rE/ 2 g[t] + ( 16*rE)/( 6 \[Pi]) g[t] s[t], 
Derivative[1][g][t] == (n (4 + a d (k^2 + \[Pi]^2)) g[t])/(
  a (-1 + n) ) +  rE/ 2 g[t] + ( 16*rE)/( 6 \[Pi]) g[t] s[t], 
Derivative[1][h][t] == 
 1/2 ((2 n (4 + a (d (k^2 + \[Pi]^2) + k^2 sr)) h[t])/(
    a (-1 + n)) - (
    m (2 + m Sqrt[2 - n] - n + 
       E^((2 m)/Sqrt[2 - n]) (-2 + m Sqrt[2 - n] + n)) rE u[
      t])/((1 + E^((2 m)/Sqrt[2 - n])) (2 - n)^(3/2))), 
u[0] == 0.0001`, v[0] == 0.0001`, w[0] == 0.0001`, 
s[0] == 0.0001`, f[0] == 0.0001`, g[0] == 0.0001`, 
h[0] == 0.0001`}, {u, v, w, s, f, g, h}, {t, 0, time}, 
 MaxSteps -> \[Infinity]];
```

Plotting:

```
q1 = Plot[ u[t] /. soln, {t, 0, time}, 
PlotLabel -> Style[  "(a)       U", 20], Frame -> True, 
LabelStyle -> 12, PlotRange -> All]
```

But I get some kind of error, and I don't know what its mean.

Error

```
ReplaceAll::reps: {soln} is neither a list of replacement rules nor a  valid dispatch table, and so cannot be used for replacing.
```

I will appreciate your help and comments

Comment: running your code hanged my PC. Mathematica 11.1.1 kept eating more and more RAM and the PC hanged. I was lucky to catch it in time and be able to kill the kernel. Warning to others before running the code. Which version of M did you run the above on and how long did it take to finish? I have 16GB ram.

Comment: If you look at help,. you see the examples show the command as `Plot[Evaluate[u[t]/.soln],......]`. You are missing the `Evaluate` part?  I can't try it, since your code hangs on my PC.

Comment: In V 10.1 Removing the `MaxSteps -> \[Infinity]` takes a while and complains about `NDSolve::mxst: Maximum number of 22073017 steps reached at the point t == 0.18082486559386235` but finally finishes and changing your plot interval to `{t, 0, .180}` and don't use an 'Evaluate' shows me the plot. I'm guessing that your kernel died and there is no value in `soln` which you might try to verify. Try evaluating 'soln` after the error and see if it displays nothing but `soln`. If so that would explain the error but not why your kernel died.

Comment: In V 10.1, replacing all decimals with exact fractions, using `Simplify` on your system before giving it to `NDSolve`, removing `MaxSteps->\[Infinity] and adding 'WorkingPrecision->32` makes `NDSolve` bail after 7 seconds because it reaches 10000 steps at t==.080. Graphing each your functions without `Evaluate`  or `PlotRange` shows several of your functions appear to be blowing up.